# merge n coins with minimum cost to create one single coin

Tags: algorithm

From http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/amazon-interview-set-89/

> We have n gold coins. We need to amalgamate all the n coins to create
>   one single coin, we can merge two coins at once. The cost of merging
>   two coins is equal to the value of those coins. How do we ensure that
>   the cost of merging n coins in minimum.
>
> ```
> Ex: 5 ,8 , 4, 3, 9, 6
> We will merge 3 and 4, cost=7 {Remaining coins: 5,8,9, 6,7}
> Then we merge 5 and 6, cost=11 { Remaining coins: 11,8,9,7}
> Then we merge 7 and 8, cost=15 { Remaining coins: 11,15,9}
> Then we merge 9 and 11, cost=20 { Remaining coins: 20,15}
> Then we merge 20 and 15, cost=35 { Remaining coins: 35}
> Total cost: 7+11+15+20+35 = 88
> ```
>
> If we had merged the coin array {5, 8, 4, 3, 9, 6} in different
>   fashion:
>
> ```
> Merging 5 and 8, cost=13 {Remaining coins: 13, 4, 3, 9, 6}
> Merging 13 and 4, cost=17 {Remaining coins: 17, 3, 9, 6}
> Merging 17 and 3, cost=20 {Remaining coins: 20, 9, 6}
> Merging 20 and 9, cost=29 {Remaining coins: 29, 6}
> Merging 29 and 6, cost=35 {Remaining coins: 35}
> Total cost: 114
> ```
>
> As we can see that the cost is less in the first case. how to get the
>   minimum cost of merging all the n coins??
>
> this is just an example, number of coins may of the range 10^9

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi this is just an example, coins may of the range 10^9

Comment: Unless I see a counterexample I'd assume that always merging the smallest coins is best. Because you always have to do the same number of mergers, and by this way the cost per merger should be lowest. Can't proove it, though.

Comment: @tobias_k take for example 3 4 8 9 as per your algorithm answewr should be 7+15+24=46 but answer should be 24

Comment: How do you get 24? 24 is the sum of those coins, but if you can merge only two coins at once, that can't be. Or maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @tobias_k sorry my bad let me think once more

Comment: @user3762730 Are the number of coins, say `N`, up to `10^9`? Assuming this is from a programming contest, that number is quite suspect. You will need the complexity to be at least `O(N)` and `10^9` is an order of magnitude above the "standard" prog contest constraint for an `O(N)` solution. Also, if an `O(N*N)` solution would suffice, you can recurse on consecutive subsequences and make the state-space and runtime `O(N*N)` using a DP. Let me know if it does and I can code it up.

Comment: Possible source: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/amazon-interview-set-89/  It would be nice to credit this in the question.

Comment: @user3762730: Please could you add an attribution to the source of your question?  It's word-for-word identical (including the examples) to the one I linked to in the comment above.

Comment: Good problem, though the 'merging coins' exposition is awkward.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've not given this a lot of thought, but off the top of my head, it seems pretty likely that a greedy approach will work: sort the coins and always merge the smallest ones first. The intuition behind this is that you want to "merge" the most expensive coin as infrequently as possible.

If you have one coin, you're done. If you have two coins, you have only one choice. Consider the case with three coins: A < B < C. We can merge these in three ways:

```
A + B, (A + B) + C => 2A + 2B + C
A + C, (A + C) + B => 2A + 2C + B
B + C, (B + C) + A => 2B + 2C + A
```

We see that the first option, merging the smallest coins, is best. See Bill's answer for a valuable insight on taking the proof all the way - a comment I contributed is copied here:

You can think of the coins' values as being token frequencies used in Huffman encoding. For very frequent tokens, you want a short code path. I think Bill's pointing out that the "merging" can be thought of as sort of moving up the Huffman tree: the number of times a coin gets merged is its distance from the root. Therefore, the proof of correctness for Huffman's algorithm should apply to the (also) greedy algorithm I describe, which is basically Huffman's, though not for encoding.

Comment: Don't know whether this counts as a proof, but it seems plausible to me. +1

Comment: Sir, can we do it in O(n) time?

Comment: @AyushJain I think O(nlogn) is a better guess. You have to sort the coins and keep them in sorted order, maybe using a priority queue.

Comment: @AyushJain If the coins can only assume a relatively small number of values from a finite set, then it's possible to sort them by value in O(n) using any of the common linear-time sorting algorithms. These would not apply if coins can assume any nonnegative integer value.

Answer (score 1):

Let `C_s` be the optimal cost of merging `S = [s_1, s_2, ..., s_n]`.

Then if P and Q different only in one element (i.e. `p_i = q_i`, except for exactly one i), at index j, and `p_j < q_j`. Then we have that `C_P <= C_Q`.

Basically, P and Q differ only in a single coin with P having the smaller one. Then optimal merge for P will have lower cost than optimal merge for Q.

This proves that @Patrick87's greedy algorithm is correct.

btw, this is basically a Unary Huffman encoding!

Comment: Could you please enlarge a bit on the "Unary Huffman encoding" part?

Comment: @Codor You can think of the coins' values as being token frequencies used in Huffman encoding. For very frequent tokens, you want a short code path. I think Bill's pointing out that the "merging" can be thought of as sort of moving up the Huffman tree: the number of times a coin gets merged is its distance from the root. Therefore, the proof of correctness for Huffman's algorithm should apply to the (also) greedy algorithm I describe, which is basically Huffman's, though not for encoding.

Comment: @Patrick87 Sounds interesing; I have to give it some more thought.